# In haskell, combining "case" and ">>="

Tags: haskell, case

I have a lot of code of the style:

```
do
  x <- getSomething
  case x of
    this -> ...
    that -> ...
    other -> ...
```

Any way of me combining the "x <- ..." and "case x of" lines to eliminate the need for a variable?

Comment: I wish `case of` was shorthand for `\x -> case x of`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the bind operator [`>>=`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3A%3E%3E%3D) to pipe the `x`.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= process
    where process ["xxx"] = putStrLn "You entered xxx"
          process ["yyy"] = putStrLn "You entered yyy"
          process _       = putStrLn "Error"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this as

```
foo "this" = return 2
foo "that" = return 3

main = foo =<< getSomething
```

The nice thing about this approach is that if foo is pure then this becomes

```
main = foo <$> getSomething
```

So the code retains the same shape for somewhat varying circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something extremely close to:

```
getSomething >>= caseOf
    this  -> expr1
    that  -> expr2
    other -> expr3
```

Then I think you're just out of luck - there is no such syntax in Haskell.  But know you are not alone.  Mark Jones defined the Habit language to include a sort of monadic case with the syntax:

```
case<- getSomething of
    Nothing -> expr1
    Just x  -> expr2 x
```

He refers to this as a "Case-From" statement in the language definition.